# works locally but gives "uninitialized constant User (NameError)" on Heroku

Tags: mongodb, heroku, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm using Rails and MongoDB and Mongoid on Heroku. I'm using Devise for user authentication. `User` is supposed to be the name of the model that Devise created. When I run it locally, it's fine but on Heroku, the app crashes and has the following error in the logs.

```
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:230:in `block in constantize': uninitialized constant User (NameError)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your problem is that your model user is most probably `app/model/User.rb` rename the file so that it is `user.rb`. Also make sure inside your user model you have

```
class User 
...... 
 ....
  ...

end
```

Also make sure you run `heroku rake db:migrate`

Comment: I had this same problem, and changing the file name to lower case did in fact resolve it. Note, however, that the question is about MongoDB and Mongoid, meaning that ActiveRecord should not be used (Mongoid uses a Mongoid::Document mixin). Just the file casing bit is needed to resolve the issue.

Comment: I have the same issue, but my file is lowercase :(